# Create PDF on ajax HTML Data Including Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, pdf

```
function CallFuncation() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Method",
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(GetData) {
      //generated pdf with download including images

    }
  });
}
```

Our ajax response data  below

```
GetData = "<h1>Employee List</h1><table border="1" width="100%"><tbody><tr><th>Sr. No</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Photo</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Alpesh</td><td>alpesh@gmail.com</td><td><img width="50px" src="images/1.jpg"></td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Rajesh</td><td>rajesh@gmail.com</td><td><img width="50px" src="images/2.jpg"></td></tr></tbody></table>"
```

We required output in pdf same as below image.

[image]

Comment: Your AJAX call doesn't look like it has anything to do with creating the PDF. All you need is a library like [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to turn `GetData` into a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches to do that, if you want to generate the pdf with js in client side, you have to use some library like [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) but the problem is that you have to turn the image's url into a base64 string, you could do it [using FileReader API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/6121568) or canvas, in both cases you have to extract the image's url from the response.

Another approach, that is easier in my opinion, is to create the pdf in the server using some library like [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

Comment: We also try to base64 string and using jsPdf no anyone get image in pdf

Comment: @user3317655 Have you tried like this way https://jsfiddle.net/dox8bjcm/ ?